# Putting Envato Profile to Resume

Tags: resume

As a WordPress plugin developer I'm selling my plugins on Envato's CodeCanyon website. I want to put it to my resume and LinkedIn profile to show my skills. What should I write as a company name/title? If I write *Envato* people will think I'm working for Envato but I'm not. I'm just selling my products on Envato's website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write something to the effect of **Freelance Developer**, **WordPress Plugin Developer** or **Self Employed**, although ***only put the latter title if you really are, if it's a hobby then the first or second titles are more appropriate*** to use. I'd also add an explanation as to what you actually do as well so people have a better understanding of your work.

Explaining that you sell WordPress plugins on Envato's network of marketplaces will be enough for people to know that you're providing plugin related services on external sites for profit etc etc.